# jetty routing for angular/spa application for static files

Tags: angular, jetty

I've managed to serve a static instance of an angular application via Jetty. The problem occurs when I try to connect to a direct url from the address bar. Since all the routing is done via angular/clientside, how can I get jetty to simply allow angular to deal with all the routing. I've seen some setups that say to redirect all 404 errors to the index, but that leaves the status codes to be 404 when inspecting the request. I have yet to see how best to serve all routes to angular and provide the correct status codes with the correct page. this is my current setup:

main jetty class:

```
package example;


import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.*;
import org.eclipse.jetty.util.StringUtil;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class AngularJSWebApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // The simple Jetty config here will serve static content from the webapp directory
        String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/src";

        // The port that we should run on can be set into an environment variable
        // Look for that variable and default to 8080 if it isn't there.
        String webPort = System.getenv("PORT");
        if (webPort == null || webPort.isEmpty()) {
            webPort = "8080";
        }
        Server server = new Server(Integer.valueOf(webPort));

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setDescriptor(webappDirLocation + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webapp.setResourceBase(webappDirLocation);

        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

the web.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app>

 <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<error-page>
      <error-code>404</error-code>
      <location>/index.html</location>
</error-page>


</web-app>
```

is there a way to direct all routing to angular and serve the correct status from the front end?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Dominic Yeah, we ended up using [urlrewrite handler](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler).

Comment: Cool, do you mind adding a snippet please? I'm currently trying to get the rewrite handler to work :)